# Invalid token combination - Arbitrum

Tags: 0x

Making a quote request on arbitrum

*request:  https://arbitrum.api.0x.org/swap/v1/quote?sellToken=USDC&buyToken=UNI&buyAmount=1000000&includedSources=GMX*

I get invalid token combination as in image below:

[image]